# Optimise query sql on mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, indexing

I have a query like this:

```
 DELETE FROM doublon  WHERE id in 
( Select id  from `doublon` where `id` not in
    ( Select id
         From `doublon` 
         group  by etablissement_id,amenities_id
         having Count(etablissement_id) > 1  and Count(amenities_id) > 1
         union
      Select id
         From `doublon` 
         group  by etablissement_id,amenities_id
         having Count(etablissement_id) = 1  and Count(amenities_id) = 1
     )
 )
```

My table `'doublon'` is structured like that:

```
id
etablissement_id
amenities_id
```

The structure table it's like this:

http://hpics.li/bbb5eda

I have 2 millions rows and the query is to slow , many hours..
Anybody know how to optimize this query to execute that faster ?

**[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/be63b/52)**

Comment: I'm surprised this runs -- I usually get `You can't specify target table...` when using mysql and deletes like this...

Comment: @sgeddes . . . You can do it with nested subqueries -- MySQL materializes the subquery so the final `delete` is not actually using the same table.  More importantly, the subbest query is returning `id`, without an aggregation function and without including it in the `group by`.  The code is at risk of simply not working or working inconsistently.

Comment: @GordonLinoff -- Hi and thanks, you can definitely trick mysql by using subqueries, but I didn't think you could like the OP posted?  I thought they'd need 1 more subquery.  When I use fiddle with a quick create table and then the posted sql above, it gives me that error.  If I embed the above subquery into 1 more (so that it doesn't reference the `doublon` table), then it works -- well works is a lose phrase in this case...

Comment: Is it the DELETE that is slow or the SELECT?

Comment: The SELECT, I try the query juste with the SELECT and the results it to slow.

Comment: You need to show us the table and index definitions, as well as row counts for each of the tables. Maybe your tables are defined poorly. Maybe the indexes aren't created correctly. Maybe you don't have an index on that column you thought you did. Without seeing the table and index definitions, we can't tell. We need row counts because that can affect query planning. If you know how to do an `EXPLAIN` or get an execution plan, put the results in the question as well. If you have no indexes, visit http://use-the-index-luke.com.

Comment: It looks like you have no indexes on your tables.  Since you have no indexes, please visit http://use-the-index-luke.com to find out about how and when to put indexes on your tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is not correct, in the first place. But keep reading, it's possible that by the end of the answer I discovered the reason you need such a strange query.

Let's discuss the last subquery:

```
Select id
From `doublon` 
group  by etablissement_id,amenities_id
having Count(etablissement_id) = 1  and Count(amenities_id) = 1
```

You can use a column in the `SELECT` clause of a query that has `GROUP BY` only if at least one of the following happens:

- it is present in the `GROUP BY` clause too;
- it is used as an argument of an [aggregate function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html);
- the value of that column is functionally dependent of the values of the columns that are present in the `GROUP BY` clause; for example, if a column that has an `UNIQUE` index is present (or all the columns that are present in an `UNIQUE` index of the table).

The column `id` doesn't fit in any of the cases above<sup>1</sup>. This makes the query [illegal](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html) according to the `SQL` specification.

`MySQL`, however, accepts it and struggles to produce a result set for it but it says in the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html):

> ... the server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate, which is probably not what you want.

The `HAVING` clause contains `Count(etablissement_id)` and `Count(amenities_id)`. When `etablissement_id` and `amenities_id` are both not-`NULL` then these two expressions have the same value and that is the same as `COUNT(*)` (the number of rows in the group). And it is always greater than `0` (a group cannot contain `0` rows).

For the groups generated when `etablissement_id` or `amenities_id` is `NULL` the corresponding `COUNT()` returns `0`. This applies also when both are `NULL` on the same time.

Using this information, this query returns the `id`s of rows whose combination (`etablissement_id`, `amenities_id`) is unique in the table (the groups contain only one row) and both fields are not `NULL`.

The other `GROUP BY` query (that is `UNION`-ed with this one) returns **indeterminate values** from the groups of rows whose combination (`etablissement_id`, `amenities_id`) is not unique in the table (and both fields are not `NULL`), as explained in the fragment quoted from the documentation.

It seems the `UNION` picks one (random) `id` from each group of (`etablissement_id`, `amenities_id`) where both `etablissement_id` and `amenities_id` are not-`NULL`. The outer `SELECT` intends to ignore the `id`s chosen by the `UNION` and provide to `DELETE` the rest of them.

*(I think the intermediate `SELECT` is not even needed, you could use its `WHERE` clause in the `DELETE` query)*.

The only reason I could imagine you need to run this query is that table `doublon` is the [correspondence table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table) of a [`many-to-many relationship`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Many-to-many_%28data_model%29) that was created without an `UNIQUE` index on (`etablissement_id`, `amenities_id`)(the `FOREIGN KEY` columns imported from the related tables).

**If this is your intention** then there are simpler ways to achieve this goal.

I would create a duplicate of the `doublon` table, with the correct structure then I would use an [`INSERT ... SELECT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-select.html) query with `DISTINCT` to get from the old table the needed values. Then I would swap the tables and remove the old one.

The queries:

```
# Create the new table
CREATE TABLE `doublon_fixed` LIKE `doublon`;

# Add the needed UNIQUE INDEX
ALTER TABLE `doublon_fixed`
ADD UNIQUE INDEX `etablissement_amenities`(`etablissement_id`, `amenities_id`);

# Copy the needed values
INSERT INTO `doublon_fixed` (`etablissement_id`, `amenities_id`)
SELECT DISTINCT `etablissement_id`, `amenities_id`
FROM `doublon`;

# Swap the tables
RENAME TABLE `doublon` TO `doublon_old`, `doublon_fixed` TO `doublon`;

# Remove the old table
DROP TABLE `doublon_old`;
```

The `RENAME` query atomically operates the renames, from left to right. It is useful to avoid downtime.

---

**Notes:**

<sup>1</sup> If the `id` column is functionally dependent on the (`etablissement_id`, `amenities_id`) pair then all the groups produced by the `UNION`-ed queries contain a single row. The first `SELECT` won't produce any result and the second `SELECT` will return the entire table).

Answer (score 0):

If am not wrong this should work

```
DELETE FROM doublon
WHERE  id IN (SELECT id
              FROM   doublon
              WHERE  id NOT IN (SELECT id
                                FROM   doublon
                                GROUP  BY etablissement_id,
                                          amenities_id
                                HAVING Count(etablissement_id) >= 1
                                       AND Count(amenities_id) >= 1))
```